# Harlan Ellison (I think) short story about vampires?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, harlan-ellison

I read a story many years ago that I think was written by Harlan Ellison, which takes place in the 70's and told from the vantage point of a young man who is pursuing a woman who is part of a group/commune.

They move to LA and the group begins doing odd things and anoint the young man as the interface to the outer world, given he is the "straightest" one.  Eventually things devolve until the protagonist discovers that in the basement of the building there is swirling water and the girl and her companions have become werewolves or vampires.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is Shattered Like A Glass Goblin by Harlan Ellison published in 1968 in the anthology Orbit 4.

Rudy comes to a commune called The Hill looking for his girlfriend Kristina. Lots of drugs get consumed and everyone changes into some kind of creature. Rudy is the only one that talks to people outside the house.

Comment: Also in the collection "The Beast That Shouted Love at the Heart of the World" (1969)  His girlfriend, who has become a werewolf, asks, with very little concern, "Have you ever grooved heavily behind anything except love?",

Comment: Thanks so much - that is it, "Shattered Like A Glass Goblin".  I read this as a teen and it left a huge impression on me, but when I mentioned the plot to Ellison fans was told it was not Ellison (though was certain it was).  It's great to find out finally that my memory was, in fact, correct.